# How to split string variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this mini-function:

```
def dummy_string_management(val)
    parts = val.split(' ')
    return "#{parts[0]}" + " -done!"
end
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
myString = "This is a string"
<%= dummy_string_management(myString) %>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `split' for This is a string
```

How can I split the variable sent as the function parameter?

Comment: have you tried your code in console? Its working fine.

Comment: Nothing wrong with how code is defined, I believe. But you've obviously altered the error message. Please, paste it in as-is.

Comment: I just tried it on the console and it worked just fine

Comment: It's worth noting here you can do `"#{parts[0]}-done!"` as one string, no `+` necessary, and additionally you can omit the `return` as that's implied, Ruby always returns the last value generated in a method.

Comment: `"#{ val.split.first } -done!"`  is even better. No need to create a variable if it is only used once (and on the next line).

Comment: `val.split.first` is even better.

Comment: I should have post the REAL code. This one works. the real call is this: ``dummy_string_management(myString.mainString)``.

Comment: what is `myString.mainString`?

Comment: **That** should have raised a `NoMethodError`, huh.

Comment: @DaseinA, we edit questions that have content that detract from the question. Stick to the facts: We're not really concerned with your skill level and want to know the details necessary to answer the problem. Stack Overflow questions are not a conversation, they're a Q&A where we help you get answers. Edits to the questions are done for that purpose, to help you. Fluff removed is for that purpose. And, when someone with significantly more experience with the site than you tries to help you, it's good to be appreciative. We do it to help you and the site.

Comment: Down-voting because obviously not pasting the code they're using, and says as much in a comment below!

Comment: Stop commenting and downvoting people. He changed his username and updated his profile to read "Delete my account." You help whoever can be helped, and let the rest do whatever they will.

Answer (score 6):

Using IRB to test your code:

```
>> def dummy_string_management(val)
|        parts = val.split(' ')
|        return "#{parts[0]}" + " -done!"
|    end
:dummy_string_management
>> dummy_string_management('foo bar')
"foo -done!"
```

So, the code is behaving correctly. (It's not well written Ruby but that's a different problem.)

You can't use

```
myString = "This is a string"
<%= dummy_string_management(myString) %>
```

in a view/ERB template. The line `myString = "This is a string"` won't be interpreted as you expect, nor should you get the error message you said. At a minimum you need to define the variable inside `<% ... %>` but really that should occur in a controller and the result of `dummy_string_management(myString)` should be assigned to a variable which is directly accessed in the view.

Just as an idea of how we'd probably write your method:

```
def dummy_string_management(val)
    val.split.first + ' -done!'
end
```

How that works is left for you to figure out.

Comment: `split` is definitely better than `split(" ")`. But I believe that the behavior of String#split with no args may be different in older Ruby versions.

Comment: Actually I'm doing this: ``dummy_string_management(myString.mainString)`` so I'm sending an object ??

Comment: **WHAT?!?! POST WHAT YOU'RE ACTUALLY USING IN YOUR QUESTION!**

Comment: `split` behavior (without a parameter) has been stable since at least [Ruby 1.8.6](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/String.html#method-i-split).